# Using Limit on Distinct group by values psql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a table that looks like this or maybe I am going nowhere.

```
create table customers (id text, name text, number int, useless text);
```

With values

```
insert into customers (id, name, number, useless)
values
('1','apple',1, 'a'),
('2','banana',3, 'b'),
('3','pear',2, 's'),
('4','apple',1,'e'),
('5','banana',3,'s'),
('6','cherry',3, 'a'),
('7','cherry',4, 's'),
('8','apple',2, 'd'),
('9','banana',4, 'c'),
('10','pear',5, 'e');
```

My failed psql query is this.

```
select id, name, number, useless
from customers
where number < 4
group by customers.name limit 2
```

the query i want to use that it returns first 2 unique grouped by customers.name. Not the first 2 rows

In the end I want it to return

```
    ('1','apple',1, 'a'),
    ('4','apple',1,'e'),
    ('8','apple',2, 'd'),
    ('2','banana',3, 'b'),
    ('5','banana',3,'s'),
```

so it returns the first 2 grouped names. 
How can I make this query?

Thank you.

Edit:

this query is my second try I know I am kinda close.

```
select t.id, t.name, t.ranking
from (
SELECT id, name, dense_rank() OVER (order by name) as 
ranking
FROM customers
group by name
) t
where t.ranking < 3
```

Comment: which version of postgres you are using?

Comment: its postgres 9.6

Comment: this query is my second try I know I am kinda close.

    select t.id, t.name, t.ranking
    from (
    SELECT id, name, dense_rank() OVER (order by name) as 
    ranking
    FROM customers
    group by name
    ) t
    where t.ranking < 3

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
select id, name, number, useless
from customers 
where name in (
  select name
  from customers
  where number < 4
  group by customers.name 
  order by name limit 2
)
```

---

```
| id |   name | number | useless |
|----|--------|--------|---------|
|  1 |  apple |      1 |       a |
|  2 | banana |      3 |       b |
|  4 |  apple |      1 |       e |
|  5 | banana |      3 |       s |
|  8 |  apple |      2 |       d |
|  9 | banana |      4 |       c |
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/88473/7/0)

Answer (score 0):

The `group by customers.name` function do not order your output, just group them by the customers.name, what you want to do is to order the group right? So what i think you want to do is:

```
select id, name, number, useless
from customers
group by name 
order by name []*
```

*[asc/desc] depends of what order you want to do:

- asc - ascendent,
- desc - descendent

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dense_rank()` as:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (order by name) AS rank, temp.*
    FROM customers temp WHERE number < 4) data
WHERE data.rank <= 2
```

---

```
| rank| id|   name | number | useless |
|-----|---|--------|--------|---------|
|  1  | 4 | apple  | 1      | e       |
|  1  | 1 | apple  | 1      | a       |
|  1  | 8 | apple  | 2      | d       |
|  2  | 5 | banana | 3      | s       |
|  2  | 2 | banana | 3      | b       |
```